# Price of switching control between C++ and Python

Tags: c++, python, performance

I'm developing a C++ application that is extended/ scriptable with Python. Of course C++ is much faster than Python, in general, but does that necessarily mean that you should prefer to execute C++ code over Python code as often as possible?

I'm asking this because I'm not sure, is there any performance cost of switching control between code written in C++ and code written in Python? Should I use code written in C++ on every occasion, or should I avoid calling back to C++ for simple tasks because any speed gain you might have from executing C++ code is outmatched by the cost of switching between languages?

**Edit:** I should make this clear, I'm not asking this to actually solve a problem. I'm asking purely out of curiosity and it's something worth keeping in mind for the future. So I'm not interested in alternative solutions, I just want to know the answer, from a technical standpoint. :)

Comment: Is it an option to write the primary application in Python, and use C++ to write a Python module that your application can use? Then the cost of switching languages should be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost is present but negligible. That's because you probably do a fair bit of work converting python's high level datatypes to C++-compatible representations. Of course this is similar to the cost of calling one C++ function from another, there's some overhead. The rules for when it's a good idea to switch from python to C++ are:

A function with few arguments

A function which does a large amount of processing on a small amount of data

A function which is called as rarely as possible - consolidate function calls if possible

Comment: In order: 1. what does the number of arguments have to do with anything? 2. What about a large amount of processing on a *large* amount of data? Can't C++ do that? 3: If it's rarely called, why on earth would you go through the tremendous effort of converting it to C++? Seems like you should concentrate on the ones that actually eat up processing time.

Comment: @Chris: 1. As Dan says, it's usually pretty clumsy accessing arguments from an interpreter.  If you needed a function taking a hundred numeric arguments just to return their sum, it wouldn't make a lot of sense to call across to a C++ implementation.  Same concept guides "large...processing...small...data" - if you can pass the C++ code fewer arguments (even if they are say large arrays) and it's doing something complex like say optical character recognition on the data, then it's very likely worth implementing/calling in C++.

Comment: @Chris: 3. "as rarely as _possible_" - say each of billions of passes through a tight loop needed to apply some weird, complex maths function to 20 values.  Consider consolidating the C++ calls so one call into C++ is given all 20 values at once, returning their results together.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know there is a concrete rule for this, but a general rule that many follow is to:

- Prototype in python.  This is quicker to write, and *may be* easier to read/reason about.
- Once you have a prototype, you can now identify the slow portions that should be written in c++ (through profiling).
- Depending on the domain of your code, the slow bits are usually isolated to the 'inner loop' types of code, so the number of switches between python an this code should be relatively small.
- If your program is sufficiently fast, you've successfully avoided prematurely optimizing your code by writing too much in c++.

Comment: This is patently biased, as if every application was better written in Python.  Python doesn't scale (in lines of code or performance or data handling) the way C++ does and is not suitable for many of the uses to which C++ is put.  The question suggests an existing C++ program that needs some run-time interpretation for customisability.  "quicker to write, easier to read/reason about" is just nonsense - with python it's easier to find libraries to get started on "yet-another-" class problems quicker, but a mature C++ environment with libraries customised for the work can be better again.

Comment: @Tony, readability generally is subjective (That's why I said there's is no concrete rule), and I'm sure it's (python) not right for every domain of problem.  For the things I've worked on, however, it has scaled nicely in terms of LOC and expressivity.  One last note on bias... most c/c++ things I look at are very hard to read for me, but that's probably because I'm a python guy.  Your profile says you are very much a c++ guy, so that'd explain your opinion.

Comment: Also, this question is asking for a biased answer, as no one (without seeing his exact program) can say with certainty the *best* option for him.

Comment: this question asks nothing about the choice of C++ host with embedded interpreter vs Python interpreter calling C++ library: you choose to jump on that ;-P. The question provides the former scenario and asks for information about performance implications of calling between the two. I don't see much that's relevant in your answer....

Comment: I didn't say he needed to write his entire app in python... Either way, you have your opinion, I have mine.. you have your answer.. I mine.  I don't think further comments along these lines are constructive to the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple and tune performance as needed.  The primary reason for embedding an interpreter in a C++ app is to allow run-time configuration/data to specify some processing - i.e. you can modify the script without recompiling the C++ program - that's your guide for when to call into the interpreter.  Once in some interpreter call, the primary reasons to call back into C++ are:

- to access or update some data that can't reasonably be exposed as a parameter to the call (or via some other registration process the interpreter supports)
- to get better performance during some critical part of the processing

For the latter, try the script first (assuming it's as easy to develop there), then if it's slow identify where and how some C++ code might help.  If/where performance does prove a problem - as a general guideline when calling from C++ to the interpreter or vice versa: try to line up as much work as possible then make the call into the other system.  If you get stuck, come back to stackoverflow with a specific problem and actual code.

Answer (score 0):

The best metric should be something that wieghs up for you....

- Makes development, debugging and testing easier (lowers dev cost)
- Lowers the cost of maintenance
- meets the performance requirement (provides solution)